# Work With StaggeredGridLayotManager?

Tags: java, android, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I want to use a StaggeredGridLayoutManager to have a vertical list with two columns and each row has 3 parts.
What exactly should I do?

Comment: how about searching before asking? I think that is definitely what you should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this to  use `StaggeredGridLayotManager`

```
private StaggeredGridLayoutManager gaggeredGridLayoutManager;
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);    
gaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 1);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gaggeredGridLayoutManager)
```

here is the tutorial link [working with StaggeredGridLayotManager](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

suppose you want to attach it to a recyclerview, you can add add like this

```
  StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager=new 
  StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
```

where recyclerView is the `RecyclerView` object