# Add Constraint to RecyclerView Item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, linearlayoutmanager

I would like to implement a horizontal recycler view. I would like to have all the item have the same size. However if I use wrap_content in item layout_height, each item would have different height. How can I enforce recycler view to the max height of all items, and all items will fill the max height too?

I would like to have a constraint layout manager in recycler view but looks like it is not supported.

Also recycler view would only wrap content for the first N items displayed on the screen, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325075/horizontal-recyclerview-follows-first-item-height-with-wrap-content). I don't know how to get the max height of all items at beginning.